# How can I generate a select from an aliased table in Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I need to generate SQL using Arel with the form

```
SELECT c2.user_id, MAX(c2.created_at) as max_created_at
FROM comments AS c2
GROUP BY c2.user_id
```

to be used as a subquery in a larger query

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
INNER JOIN (...subquery...) s1
ON comments.user_id = s1.user_id
AND comments.created_at = s1.max_created_at
```

and I can't figure out how to alias the `comments` table in the subquery.

The closest I can get is

```
c2 = Comment.arel_table.alias
s1 = Comment.arel_table.project(
    c2[:user_id], c2[:created_at].maximum.as('max_created_at')
    ).group('user_id').as('s1')
```

but this generates the incorrect SQL

```
SELECT c2.user_id, MAX(c2.created_at) as max_created_at
FROM comments
GROUP BY c2.user_id
```

(Errors because c2 isn't defined)

Generating the query without aliasing leads to incorrect results as the table names inside and out the subquery collide.

This gives the error that `Arel::TableAlias` has to `project` method.

```
s1 = c2.project(...
```

How can I query an aliased table using Arel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`from`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel%2FSelectManager:from) to tell it which table (or in this case, table alias) to project from:

```
c2 = Comment.arel_table.alias
s1 = Comment.arel_table.
  project(c2[:user_id], c2[:created_at].maximum.as('max_created_at')).
  from(c2).group('user_id').as('s1')
puts s1.to_sql
# (SELECT "comments_2"."user_id", MAX("comments_2"."created_at") AS max_created_at
#  FROM "comments" "comments_2" GROUP BY user_id) s1
```